# Cocos2dx: How to play sprite frame animations in sequence

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a large sprite-sheet that is 8192 * 8192, and it does not support by cocos2dx. Therefore I split into 3 pieces(4096 * 4096 each). But how do I run those for sprite-sheet in sequence?

Here is part of my code. I am new in cocos2dx.

```
cocos2d::SpriteFrameCache* cache_1 = cocos2d::SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
cache_1->addSpriteFramesWithFile("cutSceneTexture_1.plist");
// same for cache_2 and cache_3 ...

SpriteBatchNode* spritebatch_1 = SpriteBatchNode::create("cutSceneTexture_1.png");
// same for spritebatch_2, and spritebatch_3 ...

Sprite* spriteFrameOne = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("InfectionAnimation1.png");
spriteFrameOne->setPosition(cocos2d::Point(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2));
spritebatch_1->addChild(spriteFrameOne);
this->addChild(spritebatch_1, 5);
// same for spriteFrameTwo and spriteFrameThree but different frameName...

cocos2d::Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames_1(18);
cocos2d::Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames_2(18);
cocos2d::Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames_3(18);

char str[100] = {0};

for(int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
{
    sprintf(str, "InfectionAnimation%d.png", i);
    SpriteFrame* frame = cache_1->getSpriteFrameByName( str );
    animFrames_1.pushBack(frame);
}
// ... same for animFrames_2 and animFrames_3

auto animation_1 = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames_1, 0.08f);
auto animate_1 = Animate::create(animation_1);
auto animation_2 = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames_2, 0.08f);
auto animate_2 = Animate::create(animation_2);
auto animation_3 = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames_3, 0.08f);
auto animate_3 = Animate::create(animation_3);

// Question: how to make those three sprite frame animations run in sequence??
spriteFrameOne->runAction(animate_1);
spriteFrameTwo->runAction(animate_2);
spriteFrameThree->runAction(animate_3);
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: you load all 3 atlas plists and then you use the frames as before, cocos2d automatically picks them from the right texture atlas

Comment: You should be using one `Sprite` node to play a `Sequence` of `animate_1`, `animate_2` then `animate_3`.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks for your answering. If possible, could you give a simple demo? I am very new in cocos2dx. Thanks!

Comment: @Guy Kogus thanks for your answering. If possible, could you give a simple demo? I am very new in cocos2dx. Thanks!

Comment: I'm used to cocos2d-x v2.x, not 3.x, but I'm guessing the call would be something like `spriteFrame->runAction(Sequence::create(animate_1, animate_2, animate_3, nullptr));`